# Connect MySQL as a link server to a SQL server

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I am trying to connect my sql database as a link server to SQL server. The my sql server is on my local machine, the MSSql Server is NOT.
For that purpose I created a dataSource like:[image]

And I executed

```
Exec master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver
@server=N'MySQL',
@srvproduct=N'MySQL',
@provider=N'MSDASQL',
@datasrc=N'MySQL',
@provstr=N'DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.3 Uniocode 
Driver};SERVER=localhost;PORT=3306;DATABASE=testmysql; 
USER=root;PASSWORD=pass;OPTION=3;'

Exec master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin
@rmtsrvname =N'MySQL',
@locallogin=NULL,
@rmtuser=N'root',
@rmtpassword=N'pass'
```

Now I can see the linked server in management studio but if expand the tree or query the server I am getting the following error:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

localhost always refers to the machine in which this reference is used/defined. If the sql server instance is on machine x (and terms like "my local machine" are not useful here) and the MySQL server is on machine y, then you cannot reference one from the other (regardless of direction) using localhost. In this arrangement, localhost for the sql server machine refers to machine x - the machine running sql server.

You need to provide the appropriate address or host name.